# Matplotlib and imageai compatibility issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from imageai.Classification import ImageClassification
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

prediction = ImageClassification()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet50()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "resnet50-19c8e357.pth"))
prediction.loadModel()

predictions, probabilities = prediction.classifyImage(os.path.join(execution_path, "image1.jpg"), result_count=10)
for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
```

But I got the following error

> ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/imageai/Classification/**init**.py", line 4, in 
> from matplotlib.cbook import deprecated
> ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated' from 'matplotlib.cbook' (./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py)

I think I have a problem in the matplotlib version compatibility.